# Как эффективно импотировать базы данных?

Tags: mysql, sql

есть файл в формате **.sql** и в нем собраны все базы данных из сервера около 10 штук. Как быстро через консоль импотировать этот файл **.sql** на сервер.

Comment: если есть база, или экспортируемый файл содержить `create database` - то можете использовать `mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`

Comment: Быстро, эффективно... а это уж как получится - у тебя степеней свободы уже нету, только импортировать и ждать, пока прожуёт.